# How to convert the spanner TIMESTAMP to BigQuery TIMESTAMP?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-spanner

I am trying to copy some tables from Spanner to BigQuery.

I dumped Spanner database in csv file and when I try to upload that csv to BigQuery it is throwing error of the timestamp format.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#Limitations) they mentioned limitation of BigQuery TIMESTAMP.

How do I convert spanner TIMESTAMP to BigQuery TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Probably, you need to format the timestamp when you are porting data from your cloudspanner source. Alternatively, you can choose to go as is and keep your timestamp field as a string field during upload and parse it in BigQuery at the time of querying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted timestamp to epoch time like this

```sql
SELECT myTime , FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%s",  myTime, "America/Los_Angeles") FROM MyTable
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There may be two ways to go about this.

1. Keep the timestamp field as a string as exported by Cloud Spanner and load it into BigQuery as a string. It should still be sortable and used in predicates.
2. Use a user-defined function to do the string conversion required to load the timestamp natively in BigQuery, via the TextToBigQuery [Dataflow template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#gcstexttobigquery).

You may also write a script to convert the Timestamp to the BigQuery format.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Biswa-nag wrote -

We export our Spanner tables to avro files then import to BigQuery. 
Unfortunately, the timestamps turned out to be Strings in BigQuery.

Our workaround for ad-hoc queries is to use user defined function to convert the timestamp in the queries (it took some time to find the correct format...)

An example:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ConvertTimestamp(dt STRING) AS (PARSE_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ", dt));
select count(*) from `[db].Games` where ConvertTimestamp(StartTime) >= DateTime(2019,8,1,0,0,0)
```